# Python : Sockets with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

a new python coder here.
I am trying to make a game , where there is a 5x5 grid on numbers , and when i click on one of them , they get replaced with a cross 'X' and get greyed out. Here is the code :

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import socket

removed_numbers=[]
def numberClick(num,btn):
    messagebox.showinfo('Message',str(num)+' is removed')
    removed_numbers.append(num)
    btn.configure(text='X')
    btn.configure(bg='red',fg='white')
    btn.configure(state="disabled")
    print(removed_numbers)
root = Tk()
#root.geometry("200x200")
w = Label(root, text='Welcome to Bingo!') 
linear_array = [i for i in range(1,26)]
random_array = []
for i in range(1,26):
    temp = random.choice(linear_array)
    linear_array.remove(temp)
    random_array.append(temp) 

rows=5
columns=5
btns = [[None for i in range(rows)] for j in range(columns)]
    
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        num = random.choice(random_array)
        random_array.remove(num)
        btns[i][j]=Button(root, text = num , fg ='red',height = 3, width = 5)
        btns[i][j]['command']=lambda btn=btns[i][j],num=num: numberClick(num,btn)
        btns[i][j].grid(row=i,column=j)

#text1=Text(root,width=47,height=1,bg='grey')
#text1.grid(row=5,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Output here :
[image: When i click on a number]

Now i want to create a server , where two clients with the same code above connect , and when one button is pressed in a client , the action reflects in the other one as well. I tried to connect the client with server as shown :

Server.py :

```
import socket

c1 = None #Client socket1
addr1 = None #Client address1
c2 = None #Client socket2
addr2 = None #Client address2   
server_socket1 = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

server_socket1.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from

server_socket1.listen(2) #We will only accept two connections as of now , one for each client
print("Server started successfully!!!")
print("Waiting for connections...\n\n")

flag_client1 = '0'
flag_client2 = '0'

while (((c1 is None)and(addr1 is None)) and ((c2 is None) and (addr2 is None))):
        
    if((c1 is None) and (addr1 is None)):
        c1,addr1 = server_socket1.accept()
        print("User connected to client1 socket!!")
        flag_client1='1'
        

    if((c2 is None) and (addr2 is None)):
        c2,addr2 = server_socket1.accept()
        print("\n\nUser connected to client2 socket!!")
        flag_client2='1'

if(flag_client1=='1' and flag_client2=='1'):
        c1.send(bytes(flag_client1,"utf-8"))
        c1.send(bytes(flag_client2,"utf-8"))
        c2.send(bytes(flag_client1,"utf-8"))
        c2.send(bytes(flag_client2,"utf-8"))       
while True:
    msg = c1.recv(4096)
    if(msg!=None):
            msg = msg.decode()
            c2.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
            
    
    msg2 = c2.recv(4096)
    if(msg2!=None):
            msg2 = msg2.decode()
            c1.send(bytes(msg2,"utf-8"))
```

Client.py :

```
#Connection Part
client_socket = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from
```

But the connection is not getting reflected in server. I know i am wrong here.
Can someone please guide my how can i achieve the mentioned task? Can the same be done with Flask and socketIO? Will it be easy than tkinter? I really need to do  it for my UNI project. TIA